# What is the distribution of the number of heterozygotes in finite populations?

Tags: evolution, population-genetics, population-biology

Consider a bi-allelic locus with alleles `A` and `a`. We denote the frequency of the `A` allele by $p$. Assuming absence of selection and panmixia, the *expected* number of heterozygotes is $2p(1-p)N$, where $N$ is the population size. We can also calculate the expected number of `AA` and `aa` individuals.

**What is the joint probability distribution of the number of `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` individuals?**

Comment: The distribution would be binomial.

Comment: Thank you. I developed my question a little bit to improve it. I am looking for the joint distribution for each possible genotype. Probably some joint binomial distribution. If you know the answer, please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a multinomial (trinomial) distribution with $N$ trials, $p_{AA}=p^2$, $p_{Aa}=2p(1-p)$, and $p_{aa}=(1-p)^2$. The probability to get exactly $n_{AA}$ `AA` genotypes, $n_{Aa}$ `Aa` genotypes and $n_{aa}=N-n_{AA}-n_{Aa}$ `aa` genotypes is

$$P\left(N_{AA} = n_{AA}, N_{Aa} = n_{Aa}\right) = \frac{N!}{n_{AA}!n_{Aa}!n_{aa}!}p^{2n_{AA}}\left(2p(1-p)\right)^{n_{Aa}}(1-p)^{2n_{aa}}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I edited your answer to write out the actual distribution (let me know if I made a mistake). +1